# Unity Changing Another Class With Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, rigid-bodies

Suppose I'm trying to change a force while in a collision with a trigger. When I add the new force I also would need to cancel out the previous force in the fixed update class. How would I temporarily disable the force in the fixed update class while in the collision class? I tried adding rb.Sleep() to the collision class, but this just freezes the player. Any Ideas? Thanks.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * gravity);

private void OnTriggerStay(UnityEngine.Collider collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Trigger")
    {

        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * gravity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite clear as there could be two cases. You have a force given in FixedUpdate then on collision you want to provide a new force and stop the "constant" one.

```
 void FixedUpdate(){
     if(condition==false){return;}
     rb.AddForce(gravity);
}
```

Then toggle that condition in the collision.

But the force you apply in update is just gravity.

So you can use rb.useGravity and set it on/off.

Answer (score 0):

Really can't get what exactly you want to say But, what i got is to minus the Xforce added before this current Yforce to be added right now. if so you can use variable to hold (previous to be minuses) Xforce value and minus it first when adding Yforce.

```
Xforce = Your_Force_to_be_added;

if (condition)
{
  minus Xforce first 

  add Yforce here
}
```